# Updating a column value with the sum of multiple values in multiple tables, for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and have the following 3 tables:

1. `Employees` has the columns `Name`, `Sales`, `Bonus1`, `Bonus2`
2. `Departments` has the columns `Name`, `Score`
3. `DepartmentsMembers` has the columns `Name` (`Employees.Name`), Department (`Departments.Name`)

How do I calculate and update the value for the `Score` column for each department based on the sum of `Sales` + `Bonus1` + `Bonus2` of the employees belonging to that department?

Edit:

Based on Ali Adlavaran's answer I got this query to return the list of results with each department and their calculated `Score`.

```
SELECT 
    DepartmentsMembers.Name, SUM(Sales + Bonus1 + Bonus2)
FROM 
    DepartmentsMembers Department 
INNER JOIN
    DepartmentsMembers ON Departments.Name = DepartmentsMembers.Name 
INNER JOIN
    Employees ON DepartmentsMembers.Name = Employees.Name
WHERE 
    DepartmentsMembers.Name = Departments.Name
GROUP BY 
    DepartmentsMembers.Name
```

How can I put all that in an update statement, for each department?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, if you *need* that, then perhaps you should write a SQL `UPDATE` statement to do just that. Note that StackOverflow is not a do-the-work-for-me site. It is a question+answer site for *specific* programming questions, and you haven't even asked a question, even though you clicked a button called "Ask Question" in order to enter that text. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn what's [appropriate to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here, and how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I did read those upon registration, and I also read and tried to figure this out from previous questions that seemed related. However, logic currently fails me on how to link these 3. I posted this way in hopes of seeing a more "from scratch approach" for this "issue".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, summarize by the department:

```
SELECT dm.Department,
       SUM(COALESCE(e.Sales, 0) + COALESCE(e.Bonus1, 0) + COALESCE(e.Bonus2, 0)) as total
  FROM DepartmentsMembers dm INNER JOIN
       Employees e
       ON dm.EmployeeName = e.Name
GROUP BY dm.Department;
```

Then, you can use this in an update for departments:

```
UPDATE d
    SET Score = de.total
    FROM Departments d JOIN
         (SELECT dm.Department,
                 SUM(COALESCE(e.Sales, 0) + COALESCE(e.Bonus1, 0) + COALESCE(e.Bonus2, 0)) as total
          FROM DepartmentsMembers dm INNER JOIN
               Employees e
               ON dm.EmployeeName = e.Name
          GROUP BY dm.Department
         ) de
         ON de.Department = d.Name;
```

EDIT:

If you want to be sure that all departments get updated, then use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
UPDATE d
    SET Score = COALESCE(de.total, 0)  -- only needed if you don't want `NULL`s
    FROM Departments d LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT dm.Department,
                 SUM(COALESCE(e.Sales, 0) + COALESCE(e.Bonus1, 0) + COALESCE(e.Bonus2, 0)) as total
          FROM DepartmentsMembers dm INNER JOIN
               Employees e
               ON dm.EmployeeName = e.Name
          GROUP BY dm.Department
         ) de
         ON de.Department = d.Name;
```

Comment: This will not update the Score for departments that has no employees. You may think that unnecessary, but if a department has an employee and hence a non-zero Score, and the employee leaves, the statement in this answer will not reset the Score back to zero, but leave it unchanged with the last non-zero value in place.

Comment: @Andreas . . . If that is a requirement, then the logic is easily changed (using `LEFT JOIN` instead of  `JOIN`).  I didn't get the idea that was a requirement.

Comment: Question say it needs to *"**update** the value for the `Score` column"*. Only reason for that is that underlying data has changed. An employee leaving is a change (unless you think employees can't *ever* leave?), and since [answer by Ali Adlavaran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45655125/5221149) is [failing with `NULL` error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655063/45655510#comment78268744_45655125), having a department with no employees is definitely possible. Not resetting `Score` value to `0` when last employee leaves, is an error, leaving the database corrupt (numbers don't add up).

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
UPDATE Departments
SET Score = 
(
  SELECT SUM(Sales + Bonus1 + Bonus2)
  FROM DepartmentsMembers 
  INNER JOIN Employees ON Employees.Name = DepartmentsMembers.Name
  WHERE DepartmentsMembers.Department =   Departments.Name
  GROUP BY DepartmentsMembers.Department
)
```

I hope to be helpful for you:)

Comment: Thank you! Query runs but stops with "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Score', table 'klip.dbo.Departments'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails."
If I run the SELECT part separately, it stops with "The multi-part identifier "Departments.Name" could not be bound."

Comment: @Razvan You didn't say in your question that `Score` is defined to be `NOT NULL`. Assuming you want value to be `0` when the department has no employees, change to `COALESCE(SUM(Sales + Bonus1 + Bonus2), 0)`

Comment: The `GROUP BY` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Andreas The COALESCE resolved the error, however if I remove the `GROUP BY`, it will calculate a Score of everyone from every department, if I add it back and run a SELECT statement it displays the correct sum for each department, but it won't work in the UPDATE statement, failing with this error: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.` Question edited.

Comment: @Razvan Removing the `GROUP BY` will not calculate a Score of everyone from every department, because the subquery is limited to a single department with the `WHERE DepartmentsMembers.Department = Departments.Name` clause. Since `DepartmentsMembers.Department` and `Departments.Name` are equal, the `GROUP BY` could be on `Departments.Name` instead, giving the same result, and since that value is from outside the subquery, there will only every be one group, aka one subquery result row. Removing `GROUP BY` will also only return one row, so it's exactly the same, hence my "unnecessary" statement.